# How can I use a combobox or listbox and attach a percent for 1:M selections?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox

I am not sure what is better in this scenario because I've never used a ListBox before.

Background: I am going to develop a WinForm to add percentages of someone's bonus, (some monetary number) to different funds (stocks). `Funds Table` has these fields: Fund ID, Fund Ticker, Fund Name, Fund Description and EmployeeID as FK.

For example, Joe Smith has a bonus of $1,000. There are currently 6 active fund options he can divide his bonus into, and the total percentage must = 100%, and can be 0-100% per fund. (He has to defer his entire bonus, but cannot defer more than 100% per fund).

The combobox or listbox, whatever the best control for this, would be populated by currently 'Active' (Boolean field within the Fund table) fund options. (Basically, like a stock option to put money into.) The control would show the Fund Name.

So, Joe Smith puts 25% in one Fund Option ($250). The user would select the Fund in the 'dropdown' and type in 25 in a text box to delegate 25% towards that particular fund.

Joe Smith still has $750 left to defer into other funds. *This is where I am confused as to what to do for the user.*

What is the best way to give the user another "entry" without clearing the previously entered fields?

I'll post a screen shot of what I have and maybe that will help.
[image]

I can imagine that if the value in the Percentage text box is not 100% or have the user click an 'Add Deferrel' button then 'duplicate' the Bonus area (in the screen shot) and add it just below the current position. I don't think this is possible using Winforms, though, unless I used Visible = True or False depending on the situation, and that would get somewhat messy with screen sizing, etc.

Comment: you might want to use something like a grid so Joe can see the various distributions at a glance and not have to switch back and forth.  The grid might be ReadOnly with the controls shown being hooked up to the currently selected row (which equates to a fund).  Joe might also prefer to allocate his measly $1k by absolute dollar amounts rather than percentages.

Comment: I like the dropdown idea. I can think of some websites having buttons i.e. "Add" and "Remove" next to each row / as a placeholder to add a new row. You can add new controls at runtime for each textbox and dropdown. Id you want clarification I can put it into an answer.

Comment: So I can see why a grid would be useful if I were distributing the system to each person who had a bonus to defer, however this will be used by two people to enter in everyone's choices. The fund options, percentages and dollar amounts will all be known at this time. Which brings me to the idea of a dropdown. All options are there, I am just confused with how I should compensate on the WinForm for multiple choices. I.e: If someone opts to put 10% in each fund, how do I give the user the option to add 10 records using some kind of layout?

Comment: no matter who uses it, they cant see the work they have done so far, but your app will scold them if they only allocate 75%.  A grid allows all relevant information to be seen at once.  Add/Remove is not bad either but just emulates a grid with the overhead of dynamically added controls. Additionally, if the Fund selection is fixed/readonly in a grid, you dont have to add checking to see if FUBAR is selected in multiple input controls.

Comment: Plutonix, can we discuss this in a chat later this evening?

Comment: If you have potentially 50 different funds, but the average person allocates to 10 funds, you are wasting 40 rows in the grid and space on the window. Easier yes, less overhead yes. I would still dynamically add/remove rows. That's what my company's IRA website has anyway.

Comment: @DanVerdolino can you elaborate on the 'dynamically add/remove rows' portion? I think that's going to be my approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the concept.

To test it, on a fresh form, put a text box (TextBox1), and two buttons (Button1, Button2).

Paste this code:

```
Dim index As Integer = 1
Dim yMargin As Integer = 10 ' the vertical spacing between rows of controls relative to the textboxes

Private Sub addEntry()
    Dim txt As New TextBox With
        {.Size = TextBox1.Size,
         .Location = New Point(
             TextBox1.Location.X,
             TextBox1.Location.Y + index * (TextBox1.Height + yMargin)),
         .Visible = True,
         .Text = index.ToString,
         .Name = "txt" & index.ToString()} ' , etc., other visual features
    Me.Controls.Add(txt)
    index += 1
End Sub

Private Sub removeEntry()
    If index = 1 Then Exit Sub
    index -= 1
    Me.Controls.Remove(Me.Controls("txt" & index.ToString()))
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    addEntry()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    removeEntry()
End Sub
```

Basically replicate this for your other controls. It should show you how you can add controls dynamically. You can also add event handlers for each one among many other things.

Comment: Pretty cool! I like it. I'll have to dive into it and work with it. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use a custom panel that contains a label for the fund name a numericupdownbox to set the percentage, and perhaps a label identifying it as a percentage, or any combination of controls you feel would be necessary for each fund identified. You can use a list of panels and set a common valuechanged event handler to make sure the total percentage doesn't go over 100.  Declare and add/highlight new panels every time the user chooses a fund.

Panels are basically a container for controls.  If you set up a panel the way you want, in the designer, then create a class that inherits from Panel.  You can add the controls you need and set the properties in the New constructor.  Now adding a new panel means declaring an abject as a new instance of your class, setting the location and adding it to your form's Controls collection.  Here's an example of how the class can be set up:

```
Class BonusPanel
    Inherits Panel
    Friend PercentUsedLabel As New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Friend FundLabel As New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Private TotalLabel As New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Private PercentLabel As New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Friend WithEvents NumericUpDown1 As System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown
    Public Sub New()
        FundLabel.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left
        FundLabel.AutoSize = True
        FundLabel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
        FundLabel.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        FundLabel.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(3, 20)
        PercentLabel.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top
        PercentLabel.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(145, 2)
        PercentLabel.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(62, 13)
        PercentLabel.Text = "Percentage"
        TotalLabel.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top
        TotalLabel.AutoSize = True
        TotalLabel.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(234, 2)
        TotalLabel.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(31, 13)
        TotalLabel.Text = "Total"
        PercentUsedLabel.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D
        PercentUsedLabel.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(53, 18)
        PercentUsedLabel.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(222, 20)
        Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None
        Controls.Add(PercentUsedLabel)
        Controls.Add(TotalLabel)
        Controls.Add(FundLabel)
        Controls.Add(PercentLabel)
        Controls.Add(NumericUpDown1)
        Size = New System.Drawing.Size(293, 42)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I'll have to do more research on panels and their functionality. As of right now I have never used them nor know what they are capable of. I wish there was a better way for me to visualize your answer, step by step.

Comment: @MarkLaREZZA  I added more info for you